# The codes after exec() in the Qt thread are not implemented

Tags: qt

I find in the code body of `run()` function for a thread, the codes following `exec()` (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#exec) are will not be implemented until the application is quitted. For example:

```
myClass::run()
{
   qDebug()<<"Before exec()";

   //do some work, e.g., signal-slot connections based on a QTimer object

   exec();

   qDebug()<<"After exec()"; //this piece of code is implemented only after the application is quitted. 

}
```

I wonder if this observation is generic or just applicable to certain cases. Anyone can explain this for me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to Qt doc (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#exec), `exec()` means entering the event loop and waiting  until exit() is called. This is probably why the codes following `exec()` are implemented after exiting application.